# How to run console application once every month in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, console-application

I have created a C# console application that needs to run once every month. The company i work at uses Azure, so I wanted to use a Azure service to run the application. But I have a hard time finding the right service for the job. I have looked at Logic apps, but is unsure if that is the right solution.

Does anyone know a Azure service which is able to run a C# console application once every month?

Comment: I've not used it, but does Azure Scheduler do something like this?

Comment: hmmm Scheduler? or logic apps i guess can do it as well

Comment: Console apps need a VM to run. Lambdas/Functions, don't. You can use Scheduler or Logic apps with a Lambda and never have to pay for a VM. If you *do* pay for a VM, you can just create a scheduled job on it using the OS's job schedulrer - cron in Linux, Scheduled Tasks in Windows

Comment: Seems [Scheduler has been retired, so one should use Logic Apps instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/migrate-from-scheduler-to-logic-apps).

Comment: When i read about logic apps, it dosent't seem that it is possible to run an application, only call an endpoint or something like that. Is this true? I don't really know what you mean when you say lambda in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how complex your console app is, I guess it just starts and does a simple task. This is what Function Apps are for. They consist of a single function that can be run on schedule, or triggered by a system event.
Here is MS Docu on how to run it on schedule: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function

It does not answer your question directly (how to run a console app), but if you are asking about Azure, I'd say it's a good Azure way to achieve what you want, and is not very far from a pure console app. Azure will care about launching it and the environment.
Function Apps can also be tested locally run like a cosole app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately the console application is quite complex. I have looked at Function Apps, but didn't think it would do the job because the application is complex.

Comment: Well, it's for you to decide :) Just for thinking: basically you can pack a lot of code into a function app, you don't have to write it in a signle "function". It's just that a single function is called, kind of like Main in a console app. You can use packages and dlls in a function app, access other Azure services (e.g. KeyVault) etc. There is now VS support for this, so it's really a standalone project. The idea is: call the function whenever necessary to fulfill a specific task. It's also cheaper than running a VM in Azure or a WebApp, if that's a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Azure Automation Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-account)** for these needs.

It also allows you to run scheduled tasks directly on premisses.

Comment: So just to be clear, with Azure Automation, I will be have to upload an application and run it on a VM every month? If thats true, then it is just what I need!

Comment: Yes. You would need to run Runbook (PS script for starting application or entire VM, etc.) You can even have your application locally installed on-prem or in the cloud VM, configure Hypred Worker for this needs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-windows-hrw-install

Comment: Basically, it is a script and scheduler, sort like cron on Linux machines but in Azure cloud. It can be used for a variety of tasks. The trick is how you are going to use it, because you can run Runbook (script) in cloud or on-premise. I recommend you to read more white pappers regarding Automation account. Once you figure out you will be using it for every automation task you have.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please mark it as best. Thank you!

Comment: For instance, https://sharegate.com/blog/how-to-start-stop-virtual-machines-with-azure-automation

Answer (score 0):

Function app is definitely a better and more flexible solution.
You can use Function apps to run a console application (any exe for that matter).
Please check this [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/samples/azure-samples/functions-dotnet-migrating-console-apps/run-console-apps-on-azure-functions/). It uses an HTTP trigger to kick off the execution but in your case you could use a Timer trigger.

If you want to skip the process of downloading the binary from an external location, you could even copy the exe file to your function app folder. The steps are [here](https://www.francoisdelport.com/2018/02/13/how-to-run-console-applications-on-a-schedule-on-azure-functions/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Have you tried it, because what it read from the second link is that it is experimental.

Comment: Both the options are just a "hack" to get it working until you port the code to a function app. We used the first option but depending on your environment, getting exe files from a share/cloud storage may or may not be allowed. Hence suggested the alternate option as well

Comment: The problem is that the applicarion is quite big and complex, maybe the second option is the answer